# Reading cookie using asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a JavaScript client that sets a cookie using

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC";
```

I want to read this cookie on server side using ASP.NET Web API (running on .NET 4.5) but when I inspect request object, I do not see the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Asp.Net you are referring to but according to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies

You can retrieve cookies using something like:

```
var userName = Request.Headers.GetCookies("userName").FirstOrDefault()?["userName"].Value;
```

In a web api 2 controller you will also need a reference to `System.Net.Http`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cookies in any action filters (authorization for example), please use the below code to access to them.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext context)
{
    var cookie = context.Request.Headers.GetCookies("your-cookie-name").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.if you are want to get cookie value in service then you can use this:-

service Class

```
public class CookieService : ICookieService
 {
     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

     public CookieService(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
     {
         _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
     }
     public string GetCookieValue()
     {
         string cookieValue = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["your Cookie Name"];

         return cookieValue ?? string.Empty;
     }
 }
```

Interface:-

```
public class ICookieService
{
 string GetCookieValue();
}
```

and you should have to add inject dependency in you startup.cs class for IHttpContextAccessor

```
 Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

2.if  you want to get cookie value in controller then you can use this:-

```
var cookieValue = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["your cookie value"].FirstOrDefault()
```