# How to check cookie options on server side using C# ASP.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm creating a cookie with the following options:

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
    Secure = true
};
Response.Cookies.Append("myCookie", customerToken, cookieOptions);
```

I would love to validate when I get the cookie back from the browser that it's still created with httponly, samesite and secure before accepting it. Or is this just silly, can all of those be faked in the browser?

Comment: `Request.Cookies`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading cookie using asp.net web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092657/reading-cookie-using-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: I have no problem reading the cookie, that all works just fine. I want to see the options of that cookie as its sent from the client to the server to validate that it was sent HttpOnly, with SameSite and Secure set. If a user creates the cookie manually, I'm not sure they can set all those (if they can, this is a mute point), so I'd like to see them on the server side just as I set them on the server side when I sent it.

Comment: I'm guessing this is all for naught... just playing with chrome developer tools and I can edit the httponly, samesite and secure attributes for a cookie. So, checking them when submitted doesn't seem like it really means anything anyways!

Comment: browser agents do not send that cookie metadata back to the server. Key/Value pairs is all they send.

Comment: Thank you Rex, that's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Interesting because the cookie api in asp.net had this

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned to validate, above should be the part of authorization.
You can do it by use policy based Authorization where you can define policy's terms and conditions to be meant before executing any action.

How to guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#apply-policies-to-mvc-controllers

First you read the cookie data from request. and can use attribute authorization like: `[Authorize(Policy = "your policy name ")]` at endpoints/controller level

after that implement handler like : [Auth Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorization-handlers)  where you define your above mentioned conditions. It will fail the authorization if the token/cookie is not as per your conditions in handler.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback so far, it looks like that information is not accessible, it is not even sent from the client to the server, only key/value pairs. That being said, even if it was accessible, it can be manipulated by the browser which invalidates my use case to begin with!